# How to pass large number of parameters to a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am having a  **main form named "add.cs"** containing user information (its name , age ....etc.) on this form i have drag a button to add the user's children information (their name , blood group , date of birth..etc)whose click event opens a form "addchild.cs" on which i have dragged two button one for stroring data and another to add controls at runtime. To add controls at runtime i have used this coding

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                childrenCount++;

                Label lblchild = new Label();
                lblchild.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                lblchild.Location = new Point(20, (childrenCount - 1) * 50);
                lblchild.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
                lblchild.Text = "Child  " + (childrenCount - 1);
                TextBox tName = new TextBox(); //TextBox for the name
                tName.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                tName.Location = new Point(120, (childrenCount - 1) * 50);
                tName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(135, 60);
                tName.Text = "";
                DateTimePicker calendar = new DateTimePicker();
                //MonthCalendar calendar = new MonthCalendar(); //Calendar to choose the birth date
                calendar.Location = new Point(310, (childrenCount - 1) * 50);
                ComboBox bloodGroup = new ComboBox(); //ComboBox for the blood group
                bloodGroup.Location = new Point(650, (childrenCount - 1) * 50);
                bloodGroup.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(135, 60);
                for (Enum.Blood_Group l = Enum.Blood_Group.O_negative; l <= Enum.Blood_Group.AB_positive; l++)
                {
                    bloodGroup.Items.Add(l);
                }

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(lblchild);
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(tName);
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(calendar);
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(bloodGroup);


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Now I have created a separate **external class named "Childrendata"** for storing the value of controls added on " addchild.cs". These class contains all the data that i want to store.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jain_milan
{
    class Childrendata
    {
        string childname, childblood, childbirth;


        public string Childbirth
        {
            get { return childbirth; }
            set { childbirth = value; }
        }

        public string Childblood
        {
            get { return childblood; }
            set { childblood = value; }
        }

        public string Childname
        {
            get { return childname; }
            set { childname = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

then on the click event of the submission button on addchild.cs i have used this code to store the controls data to the variables of external class called Childdata.cs.

```
  private void submitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Checks the values
            try
            {
                string message = "";
                foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                { //loop throught the elements of the form
                    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
                    { //check if the control is a Panel
                        //Get the values from the input fields and add it to the message string
                        Panel panel1 = (Panel)c;
                        Label lblchild = (Label)(c.Controls[0]);
                        TextBox tName = (TextBox)(c.Controls[1]);
                        DateTimePicker calendar = (DateTimePicker)(c.Controls[2]);
                        ComboBox bloodGroup = (ComboBox)(c.Controls[3]);

                        //add to class
                        Childrendata childdata=new Childrendata();
                        childdata.Childname = tName.Text;
                        childdata.Childblood= bloodGroup.Text;
                        childdata.Childbirth=calendar.Text;


                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
         }
```

Now how can i made the constructor taking array or any other thing as parameter and that store all the values and i can call this constructor to my main page named add.cs .So on click event of a button on add.cs i may store these values into database by using coding like this.

```
Childrendata cd = new Childremdata();
Children child = new Children();

                    child.Namechild = cd.Childname;
                    child.Bloodchild = cd.Childblood;
                    child.Dobchild = cd.Childbirth;
                    if (new InsertAction().Insertchildren(child))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(" Children Insertion Happen ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(" Children Insertion does not Happen ");
                    }
```

Please tell me the exact example because i have tried a-lot to solve this but no output!!
Please help please please please

Comment: To clarify what you are asking. You want to be able to use something like a list or array to instantiate your class?

Comment: no actually i want to store the value of all the controls present in the child form to the parent form

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you create a class, called a "Model" that will contain the data for your child (like the name, blood type, etc).

This model class will become the "home" for all of the data, and you can pass it to any other form or class that needs it -- so, now you are only passing 1 parameter.

When you have multiple children, you could put your ChildModels into a collection/array/list/ or ObservableCollection (for databinding).  Then you could loop through each child in the list to manipulate them.

If you want to take that to the next step, implement System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged on your model, and use databinding to make the data visible in your form controls, instead of moving the data in and out of the controls by hand.

For more information, search for the Model View Controller pattern.

Comment: will you please give me an example please just example that how i can do this.

Comment: what's the difference between the class i created with name "Childdata" that contain all the data and the model class please tell me

Comment: Your ChildData class is a decent example of model -- you're definitely on the right track.  And having re-read your original post, I think that you are looking pretty good.  I would recommend reading up a little bit on Databinding.  Databinding will save you from writing the really tedious code involved in moving the data in and out of your form controls.  Here's a tutorial on databinding with Winforms: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look on this code:

**Add.cs**

```
public class Add
    {
        private List<Childrendata> children;   //Create this List of Childrendata in Add.cs form

        public void CreateChildControls()   // This is on Button click to create another from with controls
        {
            children = new List<Childrendata>(); // Call Add.cs form and pass the List
            AddChild obj = new AddChild(children);
            obj.StoreData();
        }

        public void StoreInDB()  // This is on final Submit to DB
        {
            if (new InsertAction().Insertchildren(children)) // Pass the same List of Childrendata to Save in DB
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Children Insertion Happen ");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Children Insertion does not Happen ");
            }
        }
    }
```

**AddChild.cs**

```
public class AddChild
{
    private List<Childrendata> m_children;
    public AddChild(List<Childrendata> children)
    {
        this.m_children = children; //Initialize the same List as sent by Mainform
    }

    public void AddControls()
    {

    }

    public void StoreData()  // This is on Submit button click in child form to add new child details
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Filled with some dummy data
            Childrendata childdata = new Childrendata();
            childdata.Childname = "skumar" + i;
            childdata.Childblood = "B" + i;
            childdata.Childbirth = "2013/10/"+ i;

            m_children.Add(childdata);   // Add to same List
        }
    }
}
```

**Childrendata.cs**

```
   public class Childrendata
    {
        string childname, childblood, childbirth;

        public string Childbirth
        {
            get { return childbirth; }
            set { childbirth = value; }
        }

        public string Childblood
        {
            get { return childblood; }
            set { childblood = value; }
        }

        public string Childname
        {
            get { return childname; }
            set { childname = value; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I upvoted this idea because of it starting to follow the model/view/presenter model which I prefer. It allows a person to unit test the form, and the data independently. Plus with this way it gives you more freedom when it comes to checking the data being entered. It may take more time to setup initially it will save you time in the future.

Comment: thanks sir, sir will you please tell me that , can i delcrare a method inside a method as you told above to create a function inside the function of button click

Comment: @user2214972: You can't create method inside other method. What I mean to say is create a separate method and call it from your button click method.

Comment: Sir, I have applied this method but this method is returning null values in add.cs form and even storing only the values of first child added at runtime not for all

Comment: @VJain: Without the complete code it would be really difficult to trace down the problem. I would rather suggest you can upload it to some free file sharing web sites, so that I can download & verify it.

Comment: @VJain: You can go to Ge.tt website and upload the same there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want exactly, but you can certainly have constructor in Childrendata class like this:

```
public class Childrendata
{
   public Childrendata(Children child)
   {
      childname = child.Name;
      //etc...
```

Comment: no i dont want this. i actually want to made a contructor in the form class so that i can store the value of all controls in it and call this in the parent form.